# OR-tools: Build time-dependent capacity in cumulative constraint

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming

Within the job shop scheduling problem, I have been trying to encode the following constraint to capture the fact that there are some resource scarcity constraints, which are time dependent (for instance: the number of workers available, based on the day or the shift)

```
for all t:
  sum(workers_required[i]
    if (start(intervals[i]) <= t < end(intervals[i])) and
    (intervals[i] is present)) <= workers_available[t]
```

To capture this constraint, I have thought of 2 methods:

1. Leverage the built-in AddCumulative

I haven't found a good & simple way to leverage this function for time-dependent capacity.

- Should I create more interval vars defined for each shift: interval[task, shift], then add 2 constraints ? (adds too much complexity)

  1. For each shift:  `model.AddCumulative(shift_intervals, workers_required, workers_available)`
  2. For each task - Continuous interval constraints:  Saying that for a single task, I want to minimise the number of intervals (i.e the number of interval presence transitions), and have them continuous one with another

However, 1+2 seems rather complex.. Is there no other way to create only 1 interval per task and to constrain this interval over different time domains ?
For instance, a way to tell the model that the AddCumulative constraint is only valid over a specific time domain?

2. Build my own cumulative constraint through time decomposition: It works but the model complexity & run-time increase by a factor 10. Approach based on Hakan work: http://www.hakank.org/or_tools/cp_sat_utils.py

If possible, I would rather go for a simplified option 1.

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed intervals with fixed demands to fill in between the the available capacity and the max capacity.

Comment: Thanks Laurent !
I didn't get your comment before... But it makes sense now.
The idea is that the workers_available remains a constant, however, I could introduce fixed intervals to consume some of the capacity on specific time intervals: model.NewIntervalVar(start, end-start, end, 'worker_off'). Is that right ?

Comment: yes, even better with NewFixedSizedIntervalVar(start, end-start, 'worker_off')